# Was the exhaust cloud at the Starship launch mostly pulverized launchpad?

Tags: launch, spacex-starship, failure, launchpad, plume

The launch of Spacex Starship on April 20 2023 looked pretty normal on first sight, apart from some engines not running, and some concrete flying around.

The huge exhaust cloud looked normal, because it is normal for a rocket using solid propellant. But Starship runs on methane and oxygen. Which burns to mainly carbon dioxide and water, and maybe some soot.

The huge plume was not black, not even dark, so it was not soot.

**Does that mean the whole large cloud was almost exclusively material from the foundation of the launchpad**<sup>*</sup>, in a very wide range of particle sizes?

When seeing it, I assumed the cloud was just a big normal exhaust cloud, with surprisingly many big pieces of concrete in it. But now I suspect this cloud was 100% concrete and sand from under it.

Note that there is no water deluge system, that creates a huge cloud of water vapor with a clean burning rocket like one burning hydrogen, and also no foam isolation that partially burns creating some dark smoke, as seen when a Delta IV Heavy starts.

---

<sup>*</sup> I want to express my respect for the engineering of the launchpad and point out that the launchpad actually worked, even after loosing much of its total mass.

Comment: Even hydrogen and oxygen fueled rockets make a huge steam plume (see Apollo launches) without incorporating concrete.

Comment: @Woody wasn’t the Saturn V RP-1/LOX? Or are you referring to a different rocket?

Comment: @fyrepenguin .. you are correct. the Saturn 5 first stage burned RP1. It was the second stage that burned H2. My mistake.

Comment: @Woody the Delta IV Heavy would be a good example though

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kg65SiK4-bI  for a nice Delta IV Heavy plume

Comment: @Woody This video shows a white cloud, and a smaller dark cloud. It burns hydrogen and oxygen. And uses a water deluge system. I assume the dark cloud is from burning isolation foam, and the white part is water vapor from the deluge system. Both is not used with Spaceship, so that supports there should be no cloud.

Comment: IIRC Starship has *some* water but not on the same scale. Just had a thought - a perfect comparison would be to look at a plume from a horizontal Raptor test firing. Minimal plume/ground/water interactions there. Would be good to also look at similar firings for other propellants/engines. I don’t have time right now but I think someone could build a good answer based at least partially on that

Comment: It's also sitting on a beach, so even without "pulverizing the launch pad", you would expect a gigantic dust and sand cloud to be kicked up. Compare e.g. the landing footage of Falcon 9 RTLS landings at the Cape, especially at LZ-2 which is used a lot less often. You get a comparatively large plume despite the fact that we are only talking about a single Merlin engine at minimum throttle settings for only a second or two. And it is a yellowish-brownish cloud, definitely not carbon soot. Now scale that up to 30 Raptors at 90% throttle for 5 seconds.

Comment: Would you consider changing your question from "purely concrete" to "mainly concrete"? Otherwise, it invites uninformative answers which basically state the obvious

Answer (score 5):

The rocket plume from Starship would not have been composed purely of pulverised launchpad, although that would have been a major component.

In addition to the launch pad debris at various grades and sizes, there would also have been a considerable amount of dust and debris in and around the launch pad and the surroundings. In addition the methalox propellant would produce vast quantities of steam that would produce clouds of condensation on expansion and cooling.

Comment: yes good point thanks I will amend the answer

Comment: I think the area around the launch pad was quite clean. But what I missed was that the cloud could actually be cold so the water from the combustion condenses. But I am not really convinced this cloud was cold.

Comment: With a relatively clean lauching area, you still expect a lot of dust to get thrown up by a powerful rocket. Any outdoor area is going to have a thin layer of dust and sand over it, especially right near the beach like that.